# Properties of the Frequency Domain to Ensure a Periodic Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, ifft, signal-synthesis

I've been working on a project to send data via sound waves.
The way I've carried this out is by encoding the data in pulses in the frequency domain, and then creating a unique sound wave containing that information.  I've used python to plot that, which has given me:

```
import scipy as sp
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


paynowString = "00020101021126380009SG.PAYNOW010100211+658128992803010520400005303702545800.005802SG59006009Singapore620401006304"

characters = []

def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

characters = split(paynowString)
print(characters)

ascii_characters = [ord(char) for char in characters]
print(ascii_characters)

positive_x_domain = np.zeros(9*len(ascii_characters))

rhs = []
xr = list(positive_x_domain)
for i in range(len(ascii_characters)):
    rhs = rhs + xr[i*9:(i*9+9)]+[ascii_characters[i]]
positive_x_domain = rhs + xr[(i+9)*9:]
positive_x_domain = np.asarray(positive_x_domain)
print(positive_x_domain)

negative_x_domain = np.flip(positive_x_domain)
print(negative_x_domain)

origin = np.array([0])

x_domain = np.concatenate((negative_x_domain, origin), axis = None)
x_domain = np.concatenate((x_domain, positive_x_domain), axis = None)
print(x_domain)


plt.plot(np.arange((-(len(x_domain)-1)/2), ((len(x_domain)-1)/2)+1), x_domain)
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.xlabel('Time [samples]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

After which, this gives me a graph that represents the frequency domain:
[image: Frequency Domain]

Following this, I then apply the Fourier Transform on the frequency graph to get:

```
sound_wave = fft.ifft(x_domain)

plt.plot((-(len(x_domain)-1)/2), (((len(x_domain)-1)/2)+1), sound_wave)
plt.margins(0.1, 0.1)
plt.xlabel('Time [samples]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.axis([-0.1, 2500, -0.1, 1])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
#end of sending the sound wave
```

This gives me another graph that represents the sound wave:
[image: Sound Wave]

However, I was trying to get a periodic sound wave, which I was not able to get from this graph. From my understanding, if the positive and negative frequencies are reflected across the y-axis, i.e. the magnitudes of the pulses in the positive and negative x-axis of the frequency domain are the same, then the sound wave produced after the Fourier Transform will be periodic.

Is there something wrong with my understanding, or does it have something to do with the sample points plugged into the IFFT?
If so, how can I ensure that the sound wave that is produced by my Inverse Fourier Transform will be periodic, as well as playable?
Thank you!

Comment: How do you define periodic here? The spectrum of a DFT is defined as the spectrum of a periodic signal (taking one period), so, yes, one may argue that by transmitting the sound wave repeatedly, you should be able to quite easily recreate the spectrum.